# JMeter works internally: why create and abandon more and more classes cyclically?

Tags: jmeter, jvm

I started to monitor `JMeter` with script running with e.g. `Jconsole` and noted number of classes goes up gradually then quickly down, then gradually up again.

[image]

Is it typical behaviour of JMeter? Maybe even JVM in general? Or particular plug-in code should be involved? I'm concerned that to decrease number of classes GC is run and that can affect continuity of generated load. I was not able to find the answer via web search now.

ADDED: Test plan includes making [HTTP request samplers, JSON Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html), using [concurrency thread group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) to increase load in steps + randomization ([Random Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller), Random Variable Config Element).

ADDED 2:
Following advice by Dmitri, I run test `JVM_ARGS="-Xlog:class+unload -Xlog:class+load"; jmeter ...` for about 60 min (3600 sec test) I got around 116 000 classes loaded and 68 000 classes unloaded, below shows all unloaded classes with times unloaded (`jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script` take most of occurrences and mean time confirm it happened sometime during the test - being technically correct not only at start or only at finish) (from Jupiter notebook):

```
                                                        time
                                                      size  mean
classname       
java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm                          978.0  29.757680
jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context                11.0    17.486000
jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.ModuleGraphManipulator 305.0   17.489377
jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script                 66845.0 2308.991561
```

Any additional advice? What to look for further?

Comment: user7294900, added info, duration is seen from chart.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is due to `some randomization` as other mentioned test elements are unlikely to cause increase in the number of loaded classes and trigger unloading.

This is [normal behavior of the JVM](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.6526&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which can unload the classes if/when they are no longer referenced by the program.

You can add the following [JVM options](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) to your JMeter startup command:

```
-XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading
```

so you will be able to see which exact classes are being loaded/unloaded at the given moment of time.

Unfortunately it is not possible to provide more information without seeing your test plan and JVM arguments, just ensure that you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article to get confidence that your test will not crash due to a [memory leak](https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-leaks) as JMeter gives enough freedom of shooting your own leg.

Comment: thank you. I added info on ramdomization: standard Random Controller, Random Variable Config Element. `-XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading` - think will try that.

Comment: XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading produces only load (tried `java XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading -version | grep unload`). Or maybe wording different? (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing))

Comment: Dmitri, I added info on what classes were unloaded, please see.

Comment: It looks like you're using [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) or calling JavaScript engine somehow else which is a form of a performance anti-pattern. Since [JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as Groovy has the best performance among other scripting engines. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) article for more information

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it.

Comment: I found JS pe-processor. I rewrote it on Groovy and now see CPU usage of groovy based task is significantly lower, but heap size and number of unloaded classes are the same - groovy too unloades thousands of classes (I checked `use cached if available` for JSR223 in test plan).  looks like jmeter needs to recompile groovy often: I have 20k loaded and 30k unloaded for about 80k samplers run each. Anything else can be done, checked?

Comment: Nothing else I can really think of, you can consider moving from Groovy to [JUnit Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) or [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) samplers, it should be the [fastest and the least resource consuming option](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance/)